# Is the empty set closed under addition?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Having trouble understanding this. The empty set has no elements, so I think that maybe it can't be false since there's nothing to make it false?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: "Closed under addition", when translated to predicate logic, starts with a $\forall$ quantifier. That's an immediate sign that it is _true_ for the empty set.

Comment: See [Empty semigroup](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_semigroup).

Answer (score 2):

This is vacuously true. For any pair of elements $x,y\in \varnothing$ it is the case that $x+y\in \varnothing$ (assuming you have defined "+"). This holds because it is a universal statement quantified over the empty set. It is true, since every pair of elements in $\varnothing$ has this property (of which there are none).

Answer (score 0):

You're correct.

If it were not closed, there would exist a pair of elements $a, b \in \varnothing$ with $a+b \notin \varnothing$. Since the empty set has no elements, this cannot be the case.